# Have no idea of what is wrong (Matrices product - C language)

Tags: c, matrix, memory-management, crash, dynamic-memory-allocation

My code stops running before it should, at some point when I type the matrix inputs. (This is code to calculate the product of two matrices, using dynamic memory allocation for the matrices.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int **alloc_matrix(size_t l, size_t c) {
    int **matrix = (int**) calloc(c,sizeof(int));

    for (size_t i = 0; i < c; i++){
        matrix[i] = (int*) calloc(l,sizeof(int));
    }
     
    return matrix;
}

void liberaMatriz(int **M, int n){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) free(M[i]);
    free(M);
}

int** multiplicaM(int **A, int l1, int c1, int **B, int l2, int c2) {
    int **matrix_res = alloc_matrix(l1, c2);

    if (c1 != l2) {
        return NULL;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < l1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < c2; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < c1; k++) {
                matrix_res[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[j][k];        
            }
        }
    }
    
    return matrix_res;
}


int main(){
    int linhas1, colunas1, linhas2, colunas2;

    printf("Digite o numero de linhas da matriz A: ");
    scanf("%d", &linhas1);
    printf("Digite o numero de colunas da matriz A: ");
    scanf("%d", &colunas1);

    printf("Digite o numero de linhas da matriz B: ");
    scanf("%d", &linhas2);
    printf("Digite o numero de colunas da matriz B: ");
    scanf("%d", &colunas2);

    int **matrix1 = alloc_matrix(linhas1,colunas1);
    int **matrix2 = alloc_matrix(linhas2,colunas2);

    for (int i = 0; i < linhas1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < colunas1; j++) {
            printf("Digite o elemento %dx%d da matriz 1: ", i+1, j+1);
            scanf("%d", &matrix1[i][j]);
        }   
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < linhas2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < colunas2; j++) {
            printf("Digite o elemento %dx%d da matriz 2: ", i+1, j+1);
            scanf("%d", &matrix2[i][j]);
        }   
    }

    int **matrix3 = multiplicaM(matrix1, linhas1, colunas1, matrix2, linhas2, colunas2);

    if (matrix3 != NULL) {
        printf("Matriz Resultado: \n");
        for (int i = 0; i < linhas1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < colunas2; j++) {
                printf("%d ", matrix3[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    
    liberaMatriz(matrix1, linhas1);
    liberaMatriz(matrix2, linhas2);
    liberaMatriz(matrix3, linhas1);
    
return 0;
}
```

I typed the inputs below and the program crashed:

```
Digite o numero de linhas da matriz A: 3
Digite o numero de linhas da matriz B: 1
Digite o numero de colunas da matriz B: 3
Digite o elemento 1x1 da matriz 1: 2
Digite o elemento 2x1 da matriz 1: 3
```

Comment: `int **matrix = (int**) calloc(c,sizeof(int));` that should have been `sizeof(int*)` which is usually twice as large.

Comment: Using `sizeof(matrix[0])` or `sizeof(*matrix)` (instead of `sizeof(int)`) would avoid the error identified by @teapot418.  In the inner allocation loop, you'd use `sizeof(matrix[0][0])`, probably.

Comment: An array of pointers to arrays is a messy structure. Consider a 1D array and 2D emulation with an accessor function if necessary. One allocation, *completely contiguous*, instead of many allocations scattered who knows where.

Comment: Following @tadman: As a bonus you get faster matrix element access, too, for avoiding double indirection...

Comment: Discussed in the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/918121/21105992

Comment: It's for 3D array allocation, but you might find the discussions and code in [Segmentation fault error in 3D array memory allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18579583/15168).  Note in particular the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18580625/15168) by [Emmet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1583065/emmet).  Releasing memory for a partially allocated array is an interesting exercise.

Comment: You might find some help at [C dynamic 2D matrices struct frustration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64922134/15169) too.